# Is it possible to use both Firebase and PHP for a single project?

Tags: php, firebase, web, firebase-authentication, backend

I've a big social networking project going on and I am amateur in web back-end. Although I've programming experience, I'm a beginner in the back end support.

I was trying to make a login page and was thinking if I use Firebase to do the user authentication? Then I would use PHP to do rest of the things like chat system or post system.

Is it possible to do so? If yes, then how should I start a session in Firebase and use it in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use Firebase Authentication in your web site that is otherwise written in PHP. Key to realize is that in this case there are two places you need to interact with Firebase:

1. From your client-side JavaScript code, you will use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) to sign in, and get an ID token.
2. From your server-side PHP code, you then [verify the ID token](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html#verify-a-firebase-id-token). You can for example use the open-source [Firebase Admin SDK for PHP](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library for that. Note that this is not an official Firebase SDK, but in my (limited) experience it works well.

The general process for this is also described in the [Firebase documentation on verifying ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), it just doesn't contain the PHP bits.

Alternatively you can just stay within the Firebase ecosystem, and not use a PHP server. For example, you can store your data in Cloud Firestore directly from the client. To get familiar with this approach quickly, I'd recommend taking the [codelab where you build a web-based chat app](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/).